# What is a good way to find maximal counts of consecutive occurrences of something in a data.frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

For example, suppose one has this `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
x = data.frame(foo=letters, bar=as.integer((rnorm(26) > 0.5)))
```

In this example, the biggest consecutive streak of `1` happens between rows 18 and 22 inclusive. What I'm wondering is, given a much larger frame, is there a good way to identify a spot like this? I normally use tables and `dplyr` and was trying `cumprod` or `cumsum` with special values but both those approaches don't seem to cut it.

Comment: What is the expected output?  Do you want to find the maximal streak or row numbers?

Comment: @akrun both, though knowing the row numbers it's trivial to then get the maximal streak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
with(rle(x$bar), {
  w = which.max(lengths*(values==1))
  cumsum(c(1L,lengths))[w+0:1] - 0:1
})
# 18 22
```

*How it works:*

We want the run of `values==1` that is the longest. Since true/false maps to 1/0 under multiplication in R, this is the run maximizing `lengths*(values==1)`. Call this the `w`th run.

`cumsum(c(1L,lengths))` contains starting positions for each run, plus an extra element at `1L+length(x$bar)`. If we select the `w`th element, we have the run's starting position. And if we select the `w+1`th element and subtract one from it, we have the run's ending position.

Comment: Thanks, I found the longest streak in my frame of 48, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

We could use `rle` to get the lengths and values of adjacent elements that are same in the `vector` (or column).  Get a logical index of 'lengths' that are equal to maximum length for 'values' that are 1.  Negate it and assign those 'values' to 0.  With the `inverse.rle` we get the `vector` in the original length.  For finding the elements that are not 0, use `which` and use `sum` to get the count.

```
 v1 <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x$bar), 
   values[!(lengths==max(lengths[values==1]) & values!=0)] <- 0))
 which(v1!=0)
 #[1] 18 19 20 21 22
 sum(v1)
 #[1] 5
```

Comment: Frank is right, my vector is running into this (it's nearly 200,000 in length)

Comment: @Frank Do I need to keep the `value!=0`

Comment: @akrun Hm, no, I guess not. By removing it, you'll be adding those positions with values==0 to the set of positions getting assigned values of zero (so, no change). (This is assuming the vector is reliably only zeroes and ones to start with.)